# xlsxwriter not applying format to header row of dataframe - Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to take a dataframe and create a spreadsheet from that dataframe using the xlsxwriter

I am trying to do some formatting to the header row, but the only formatting that seems to be working on that row is for the row height. The exact same formatting options work on the other rows of the dataframe.

Please see code below..

The red color (and the height) is applied to all rows except the header row (row 2) - the red color is applied to both row 0 and row 3, but only the height is applied to row 2

Any help would be much appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from pandas import DataFrame
from IPython import display

import xlsxwriter

WorkBookName="test.xlsx"



df3=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(WorkBookName, engine='xlsxwriter')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet",index=False,startrow=2)


workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["sheet"]

worksheet.write(0,0,"text string")
worksheet.write(0,1,"text string")
worksheet.write(0,2,"text string")
worksheet.write(0,3,"text string")


color_format = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
worksheet.set_row(0,50,color_format)
worksheet.set_row(2,50,color_format)
worksheet.set_row(3,50,color_format)    


writer.save()

display.FileLink(WorkBookName)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to change the formatting of the header so you should first reset the default header settings

```
pd.core.format.header_style = None
```

Then apply the formatting as required

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet.set_column('A:C',5, format)
```

here is complete working code

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b'],
               'b':['a','b','c','d'],
               'c':[1,2,3,4]})
d=d.groupby(['a','b']).sum()

pd.core.format.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet.set_column('A:C',5, format)
writer.save()
```

Comment: What is your Pandas version? In Pandas 0.19.1 it's `pd.formats.format.header_style` instead of `pd.core.format.header_style` ...

Comment: yes @MaxU  correct you should use this based on the correct pandas version

Comment: Awesome..Thank you!

Comment: @Shijo Bless you. I was beating my head against a wall on this one.  To all, it is important to call `pd.core.format.header_style = None` _before_ calling `pd.ExcelWriter`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have 0.22, you must do `pd.io.formats.excel.header_style = None`. Check this [git page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19386) out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, **Pandas sets the format of the index row**. There are ways to reset it, but those solutions weren't very reliable. It was also quite hard to actually format it.

The accepted answer uses the same format for all cells, while I just wanted to format the index row.
**I solved it by writing out the index columns with the desired format**:

```
import pandas as pd

# The data that we're feeding to ExcelWriter
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Col A": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "Col B": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "Col C": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)

# The Excel file we're creating
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_out.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False) # Prevents Pandas from outputting an index

# The variables we'll use to do our modifications
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

worksheet.set_row(0, 30) # Set index row height to 30

# Find more info here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-methods-and-format-properties
header_format = workbook.add_format(
    {
        "bold": True,
        "valign": "vcenter",
        "align": "center",
        "bg_color": "#d6d6d6",
        "border": True,
    }
)

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# Set format of data
format1 = workbook.add_format({"align": "center"})
worksheet.set_column('A:Z', 10, format1) # Width of cell

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the formatting of the header, you should first reset the default header settings.

Version 0.24 requires:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).