# Pandas raising: AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error when running `pd.core.format.header_style = None`:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-fb23b66754fa> in <module>()
     11 # df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
     12 
---> 13 pd.core.format.header_style = None

AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'format'
```

Does anybody know where `format` has moved to?

Comment: I never heard of that attribute in the first place.  Where did you find out about it and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe `pandas.formats.format.header_style`?

Comment: @BrenBarn I have no idea where I heard about it but I use it to remove the formatting before writing  dataframes to xlsx worksheets with xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're now looking for

```
pd.formats.format.header_style = None
```

I believe, as of version `0.18.1`. See the issue [CLN & REORG core/common.py #12503](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12503).

---

**Edit** (version >= `0.20`)

As mentioned by Jeff, this is not a public property and so is prone to move around. Now it is found in [`pandas.io.formats.excel`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.2/pandas/io/formats/excel.py#L33), which you'll have to import.

If you wanted to handle accessing it from different versions thus far (again, susceptible to change), an adaptation from [this incompatibility issue](https://github.com/taborlab/FlowCal/issues/257) might look something like

```
import packaging.version
import pandas
import pandas.io.formats.excel

def get_format_module():
    version = packaging.version.parse(pandas.__version__)
    if version < packaging.version.parse('0.18'):
        return pandas.core.format
    elif version < packaging.version.parse('0.20'):
        return pandas.formats.format
    else:
        return pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter
```

Comment: Yep that is what it is. Don't you just love it when stuff gets moved around.

Comment: you are using a non public property. since this is not part of any guarantee you should following the changes very closely.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Could you please rephrase and/or expand on this?

Comment: @measure_theory Correct, I updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: I hope the panda devs will change it at least twice so I have to find it again every time I want to make a new excel dumper

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of pandas do not use `pandas.core.format`. You can find examples in [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
df.style.to_html(df, precision=2, caption="My table")
```