# Pandas `to_excel` set font name

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to set the font name with pandas' excel writer?

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
writer = ExcelWriter("test.xlsx")
writer.set_font_name("Arial")  # this would be ideal, but no such method exists

format = writer.book.add_format({"font_name": "Arial"})
df.to_excel(writer)  # format is not applied. Need to pass `format` object somewhere

writer.close()
```

Where can I pass the `xlsxwriter.format.Format` object once it has been created?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** using a solution similar to [@miradulo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234793/5741205) we can make it working for different versions of Pandas:

```
try:
    import pandas.io.formats.excel as fmt_xl     # version >= 0.20
except ImportError:
    try:
        import pandas.formats.format as fmt_xl   # 0.18 <= version < 0.20
    except ImportError:
        import pandas.core.format as fmt_xl      # version < 0.18

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=list('abc'))

fmt_xl.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("d:/temp/test.xlsx")

df.to_excel(writer, index= False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

fmt = writer.book.add_format({"font_name": "Arial"})
worksheet.set_column('A:Z', None, fmt)
worksheet.set_row(0, None, fmt)

writer.save()
```

XlsxWriter Docs: [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)

Comment: This is almost perfect: it works in all but the header styling: I still get the default pandas' bold and calibri, even with the line that you suggest (`pd.formats.format.header_style = None`). I also tried to define the header style before creating the writer, but I still get the same result.

Comment: @gozzilli, it worked properly for me. What is your Pandas version?

Comment: 0.19.2 on MacOSX

Comment: @gozzilli, try to execute `pd.formats.format.header_style = None` __before__ `df.to_excel`

Comment: Doesn't remotely work on pandas 0.23.4 - 'pandas' has no attribute 'formats', 'Workbook' has no attribute 'add_format'

Comment: I appreciate your followup... but the edit fails with "pandas.io.formats has no module excel"... here is my `pip freeze`:
numpy==1.15.4
pandas==0.23.4
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.7
six==1.11.0
XlsxWriter==1.1.2
Could well be on my end but it is a bit of a mystery

Comment: Looking into this at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234622 and elsewhere.. @MaxU this is not your problem to solve :)

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski, I've tried to improve my answer... ;)